# PayPal tax_cart not working with 4 digits decimal number

Tags: php, paypal

My problem is so weird and it happened suddenly
if i write my code as follows :-

```
<input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value="<?php echo ($total*0.0878);?>">
```

it doesn't work but if i removed the first "0" like this :-

```
<input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value="<?php echo ($total*0.878);?>">
```

it works fine, any suggestions?

Comment: What is the result of each calculation?

Comment: the 0.0878 is totally ignored by paypal and the 0.878 is calculated properly and displayed in the paypal page

Comment: What is the result of each calculation?

Comment: what do you mean? paypal totally ignores the first value and calculates the second value in a right way

Comment: I guess you have to use "tax" field - as it is tax amount, instead of "tax_rate" which is percentage, and cannot be too small (in you case you provide paypal with value 0.0878%)

Comment: paypal sees neither 0.0878 or 0.878, but the result of the calculation, which is probably outside its acceptable range

Comment: What value do you see in the browser as the result of `($total*0.0878)`?

Comment: @pekka i don't see any values, paypal simply ignores it and never shows any taxes , if i echo it on my page it works fine

Comment: @Dagon what is that range?

Comment: @IlyaBursov it is not 0.0878% it is 8.78% and i converted it to 0.0878

Comment: @user2869402 and this is wrong, if you want to pass 8.78% to paypal - do not multiple it by total, and then try either 8.78 or 0.0878 - I suppose first will give what you want

Comment: @IlyaBursov you do tax_cart is the total amount of tax to pay on the whole cart.

Comment: @user2869402 i suspect you `value=` is ending up after that calculation as a number like 99.893 when payapl will only accept 2dp (99.89) try `<?php echo round(($total*0.0878),2);?>`

Comment: @Dagon don't think so, as 0.878 works (at least according to OP)

Comment: `i don't see any values` you *must* be seeing the values in the final, generated HTML when you use "view source" in your browser.

Comment: @dagon, YOU ARE THE MAN ! thank you so so so much, and thanks everyone, "round" solves it all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my manly ;) answer

Your calculation is ending up with to many decimal places for paypal. It does not deal with fractions of cents. So you need to make sure your tax amount does not contain fractions the easy way is to use `round()`

```
 <?php echo round(($total*0.0878),2);?>
```

the direction you round in may be dependent on the tax laws of your jurisdiction